# SQLite unexpected duplicate values on group by

Tags: sqlite

I have a simple table with three numeric columns width, heights and length

| id | width | height | length |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 11.39 | 0 | 128.33 |
| 2 | 11.39 | 6 | 64 |
| 3 | 16 | 13.44 | 8 |
| 4 | 15.36 | 1 | 96 |
| 5 | 15.36 | 4 | 288 |
| 6 | 128.33 | 16 | 96 |

Now I want to
create a list of the largest of the three values without duplicates

`select max(width, height, length)  as largest from mytable group by largest order by largest`

result is
`16, 64, 96, 128.33, 288`
Please note that the result is 5 values, as the value 128.33 occurs twice and I used group by.

So far so good...

Now I want to get the list of middle values from mytable without duplicates

`select (width + height + length - max(width, height, length) - min(width, height, length)) as middle from mytable group by middle order by middle`

I would expect as a result

`11.39, 13.44, 15.36, 96`

because 11.39 and 15.36 are both two times in the table.

But instead I get

`11.39, 11.39, 13.44, 15.36, 15.36, 96`

So although I used group by, the records are not grouped!

On MySQL it works perfectly fine. (when replacing max and min with the respective MySQL functions greatest and least)

Interesting sidenote... When using integer columns and integer values, it works as expected.

Anybody any idea what I am doing wrong?
Any other approach to get the middle value?

Comment: If you print out the values with more digits of precision, you'll see they're not exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

As Shawn pointed out correctly (thank you!), the issue is related to float precision.

I use an ugly but working workaround, which is just possible because I only use 2 digit precision in my values..

the query now looks like this

`select round(width + height + length - max(width, height, length) - min(width, height, length),2) as middle from mytable group by middle order by middle`